# Matrix function to express pair-wise distances of rows in $X, Y$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-equations

There are two real matrices: $X, Y$ with $X$ being of dimension $n_1$ x $p$, $Y$ of dimension $n_2$ x $p$.

The goal is to form the matrix $D$ of dimension $n_1$ x $n_2$ where each element $d_{ij}$ is computed as the (L2-) norm of the difference of row i of X and row j of Y:

$$d_{ij} = \lVert x_i - y_j \rVert_2^2$$

My question is how to derive a matrix formula for $D$. I.e

$$D = g(X,Y)$$

Here is my attempt at starting: I can expand $\lVert v\rVert_2^2$ as $v^Tv$ where $v = x_i - y_j$ to obtain:

$$d_{ij} = x_i^Tx_i + y_j^Ty_j - 2x_i^Ty_j$$

But I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Your expansion needs to be corrected, it has a $y_j^T$ instead of a $x_i^T$.

Comment: That is a typo, you are correct thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to "matricize" your result a bit.

Let $X\in {\mathbb R}^{p\times n_1}$, $Y\in {\mathbb R}^{p\times n_2}$, $D\in {\mathbb R}^{n_1\times n_2}$, $v_1\in {\mathbb R}^{n_1}$, and $v_2\in {\mathbb R}^{n_2}$;   where the elements of the $v$-vectors are all ones.

Then
$$
  D = {\rm diag}(X^TX)\,v_{2}^T + v_{1}\,({\rm diag}(Y^TY))^T - 2 X^TY
$$
Note that I defined my $X,Y$ as the transpose of yours.
(My brain works better in terms of column-vectors.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this response! I think I got it. The matrix of ones multiplying on the right of $diag(X^TX)$ is of dimension $n_1 x n_2$ yes?

Comment: No, $v_1$ and $v_2$ are column vectors. I think you're misinterpreting the diag() operation.  It takes a matrix argument, extracts the main diagonal and returns it as a column vector.

Comment: Oh I see, so it's forming an outer product then. That makes more sense, thanks again.

Comment: diag(X.T,X) will give us matrix with (n1), how can we multiply that v2.T which is of size n2 ? 
this is very confusing, could anyone show this in row vectors format ?

Comment: Another way to write this result is to use yet another all-ones vector 
$v_3\in{\mathbb R}^{p}$ and to replace the diag() operators by 
Hadamard $(\odot)$ products 
$$D = (X\odot X)^Tv_3v_2^T + v_1v_3^T(Y\odot Y) - 2X^TY$$
or introduce all-ones matrices $(J_x,J_y)$ shaped like $(X,Y)$ respectively 
$$D = (X\odot X)^TJ_y + J_x^T(Y\odot Y) - 2X^TY$$