# How to simplify this derivative expression

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

I am trying to calculate the derivative of the following function:

$$ \text{Tr}(SB),$$ where $$S_{ij} = \exp \left( -\frac{\|x_i - y_j\|^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)$$

---

We have $$\begin{align*}
&A_{ij}=\|x_i -y_j\|^2 \\
\Rightarrow A &= \text{diag}(X^TX)1^T + 1(\text{diag}(Y^TY))^T - 2X^TY \\
& = (X\odot X)^T11^T + 11^T(Y \odot Y) - 2X^TY
\end{align*}$$

then

$$ dA = 2(X\odot dX)^T11^T + 11^T(2(Y\odot dY)) -2(dX^TY+X^TdY)$$

We have

$$\begin{align*}
f & = B^T:S \\
df & = B^T:dS \\
&= B^T:(\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2})S\odot dA \\
& =(\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2})B^T:(S\odot (2(X\odot dX)^T11^T + 11^T(2(Y\odot dY)) -2(dX^TY+X^TdY)) \\
\end{align*}$$

Hence, by fixing $X$ we get

$$ df= (\frac{-1}{\sigma^2})B^T:S\odot(11^T(Y\odot dY) - X^TdY) $$

Is my derivation correct?

Could anyone help me to simplify the expression of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}$?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does $\|X - Y\|^2$ refer to the Frobenius norm? Also, where are you getting those entries for $A_{ij}$ from?

Comment: Are you trying to say that $\|X - Y\|$ refers to the matrix whose $i,j$ entry is $\|x_i - y_j\|$?

Comment: Also, what is the variable with respect to which you are taking the derivative?

Comment: Hi @Omnomnomnom, yes the $\|X-Y\|^2$ refers to the Euclidian distance between $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: I am taking the derivative of $f$ w.r.t $Y$.

Comment: When you say "the Euclidean distance between (matrices) $X$ and $Y$", that means that $\|X - Y\|^2$ is a scalar. Is this what you mean? If so, then why have you introduced the matrix $A$?

Comment: The expression for the distance matrix should read
$$\eqalign{
A
 &= {\rm diag}(X^TX){\tt1}^T + {\tt1}\big({\rm diag}(Y^TY)\big)^T - 2X^TY \\
 &= (X\odot X)^T{\tt11}^T + {\tt11}^T(Y\odot Y) - 2X^TY \\
}$$
(see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1125335))

Comment: Also, I think you meant to define S as
$$S_{ij} = \exp\left(\frac{-A_{ij}^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$$

Comment: @grep, thank you for the distance matrix expression. I corrected the expression in my post.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, my S is a matrix. Each element of S is obtained by the given function. I didn't write it correctly, I am still learning. I edited my question. I also modified the derivative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a bit too big for a comment, but you've almost got it.

Let's pick things up at the next-to-last step and concentrate on the gradient wrt $Y$.
$$\eqalign{
df &= -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}B^T:(S\odot dA) \\
   &= -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(S\odot B^T):dA \\
   &= -C:dA \\
   &= -C:2\Big({\tt11}^T(Y\odot dY)-X^TdY\Big) \\
   &= 2C:X^TdY - 2C:\Big({\tt11}^T(Y\odot dY)\Big) \\
   &= 2XC:dY - 2Y\odot({\tt11}^TC):dY \\
   &= 2\Big(XC - Y\odot({\tt11}^TC)\Big):dY \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}
   &= 2\Big(XC - Y\odot({\tt11}^TC)\Big) \\
}$$
where several terms were combined into the matrix
$$C=\frac{S\odot B^T}{2\sigma^2}$$
Re-reading your post, the final differential
expression for $\big(X=constant\big)$  was correct.

---

#### Update

There was a question in the comments about one of the intermediate steps.

Let $J={\tt11}^T$ be the all-ones matrix having the 
same dimensions as $X$, then 
$$\eqalign{
C:J^T(Y\odot dY) &= JC:(Y\odot dY)
\qquad\big({\rm Cyclic\,property\,of\,Trace}\big) \\
 &= (Y\odot JC):dY
\qquad\big({\rm Hadamard\,commutes\,with\,Frobenius}\big) \\\\
}$$

Comment: Thank you greg, I appreciated your help.

Comment: Could you explain how did your trick here: $2C:(11^T(Y\odot dY)) = 2Y\odot(11^TC):dY$? I tried with the cyclic property of trace but didn't get it.

Comment: @grep, could you please check my derivation in this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3750418/how-to-simplify-the-derivative-of-this-expression

Comment: The new question looks exactly like the current question with $B=AA^T$ and $X=Y$

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot for the nice explanation!