# How to simplify the derivative of this expression

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I have the following function

$$f=\text{Tr(A}^T\text{SA}),$$

where $A$ is a matrix, $S$ is given by

$$S_{ij} = \exp(-\frac{(x_i-x_j)^2}{2\sigma^2})$$

---

Here is my attempt to calculate the derivative of $f$ w.r.t $X$

We have

$$\begin{align*} 
f &= \text{Tr}(AA^TS) \\
  &= AA^T:S \\
\implies df &=AA^T:dS \\
  &= AA^T:(\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2})S\odot dS \\
  &= (\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2}) AA^T:S\odot d(diag(X^TX)1^T + 1(diag(X^TX))^T - 2X^TX) \\
  &= (\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2}) AA^T:S\odot (diag(2X^TdX)1^T + 1(diag(2X^TdX))^T - 2X^TdX) \\
  &= (\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2})(S\odot AA^T): (diag(2X^TdX)1^T + 1(diag(2X^TdX))^T - 2X^TdX) \\
  &= (\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2})[-2X(S\odot AA^T):dX + (S\odot AA^T):(diag(2X^TdX)1^T + 1(diag(2X^TdX))^T)] \\
\end{align*}$$

I am stuck with the two terms involving the diag operator,

Could anyone help me to simplify these terms and obtain the final expression of $\frac{df}{dX}$?

Best regards,

Comment: Since you're working with diag operators, 
the following identities may be useful
$$\eqalign{
a:{\rm diag}(B) &= {\rm Diag}(a):B \\
(I\odot A):B
 &= {\rm Diag}({\rm diag}(A)):B \\
 &= {\rm diag}(A):{\rm diag}(B) \\
{\rm diag}(a{\tt1}^T) &= {\rm diag}({\tt1}a^T) = a \\
}$$

Comment: Very nice identities. Thank you again greg.